# How to set password policy expiration time in WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We're trying to set up WSO2 Identity server 5.5.0 to comply our internal password policy requirements. Now we are stuck on password expiration time. We're using built-in User Store.
We'd like to set it up to 80 days but we didn't find any parameters to do so.

We've found some options in Resident identity provider in Password Policies section but not for this particular requirement.

Are there any options to set it up in carbon GUI or in any of these configuration XML files like identity-mgt.xml? Is it possible to notify users after password is expired?

Answer (score 0):

Password Expiry feature is not supported OOTB. However you can write custom event handler to implement password expiry feature. You can refer password history validation as a reference [1]

[1] https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-governance/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.password.history/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/password/history/handler/PasswordHistoryValidationHandler.java

Answer (score 0):

However I later noticed above features was already implemented as IS Connector [1] as per capabilities I have mentioned above. You can directly use Password Policy Authenticator.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+Password+Policy+Authenticator